# Where can I purchase Female Thunderbolt to HDMI cable?

Tags: hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I have a Apple Thunderbolt Display 27 which I want to use on a Windows machine with only an HDMI port. So I basically need to cable which will have female Thunderbolt port in one side and male HDMI port in other side of the cable.

Comment: I typed "hdmi to thunderbolt" into Amazon and got literally 100's of possibilities... Not hard to find.

Comment: I guess you want a Mini DisplayPort <-> HDMI adaptor. There is nothing like a Thunderbolt to HDMI cable.

Answer (score 4):

**There's no such thing as a female Thunderbolt to male HDMI cable**.  Consequently, you cannot connect an *HDMI Source* to a *Thunderbolt Display*

[DisplayPort (DP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) and [mini DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) (mDP) can drive [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) devices, but not the other way around.

> I also want to connect it to my Windows laptop via HDMI. I bought this
>   converter, which converts the HDMI signal to DisplayPort. Everything
>   plugs in just fine, but the display just does not turn on.

Source:  [how do I connect an Apple Thunderbolt display to a PC?](https://superuser.com/q/540751/468733)

In short, HDMI simply cannot create the "signaling" required for a DP or mDP signal.  **The Thunderbolt display is more than a display; it's a Thunderbolt hub/dock with a display attached to it.**

[image]

From this picture, you can see all the ports that the display comes with:

- 3 USB ports
- 1 Firewire Port
- 1 Ethernet Port
- 1 Thunderbolt Port

**As such, this is not a mDP or DP monitor**.  You need a Thunderbolt signal to drive this monitor and HDMI simply can't do it.

**What will drive this monitor?**

Per [Apple's Support Page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP642?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) on the Thunderbolt Display....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you want to be looking for is Mini DisplayPort to HDMI (unless you have a windows machine with a thunderbolt port in that case you would just use a thunderbolt to thunderbolt, but I am assuming you don't). Here is a [cheap Mini DisplayPort (which fits in your thunderbolt port) to HDMI cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003OC6LWM), here is a more reputable [Amazon branded adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NH13K8S) (for this one you would need a spare HDMI cable).

In case you don't know ThunderBolt uses Mini DisplayPort for its video connections so if you are looking for a cable just for video searching 'mini displayport to HDMI cable' will likely yield more results than 'thunderbolt to HDMI cable'.

EDIT: If you want something in store BestBuy usually has Mini DP to HDMI cables in their apple section.

Comment: Those cables do the opposite of what the OP has asked.  The point is to connect an Apple display (with only a thunderbolt plug) to a windows PC which has an HDMI.  Thus, the "female thunderbolt port" and "male HDMI port".  All of the items I see at Amazon are male thunderbolt, and female HDMI.

Answer (score 1):

Has the OP tried this? It should work.

1. Connect the male Thunderbolt Cinema Display cable into the female end of a Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt (male) adapter.
2. Next, connect the male thunderbolt end from step 1 into the female end of a Thunderbolt to HDMI (male) adapter.
3. Connect the HDMI male end from step 2 into the HDMI port (female) of the Windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cheap, yet very reliable version of what you're looking for. I use this on my own MacBook Pro, when I want to connect to my tv for a 32" monitor...

[mini DisplayPort/thunderbolt to hdmi connection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YONKZ72)

As for what you're looking for exactly, I don't think they make a female thunderbolt adapter. If you look online, they're all male

Answer (score 0):

I just incidentally solved this problem while trying to figure out how to use one Thunderbolt display with 2 macbook Pros [[which I explained here]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272543/how-to-switch-between-two-macs-and-one-thunderbolt-display/407085#407085).

If you want to use a Thunderbolt display with a PC that only has HDMI you can use a mini displayport f to HDMI cable ([like this one for $50](https://amzn.to/3kSC1QD)).  You could also do the longer solution with a switch that I describe in that other post.

If you want to do Thunderbolt to a PC with USB-C you can use a cable [like this (for $13).](https://amzn.to/339F1lQ)

Comment: Unfortunately, the description of the linked HDMI adapter https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07H29J86N/ specifically states that it does not work with Thunderbolt displays. The USB-C adapter description says the same thing (that it is only compatible with Mini DisplayPort displays, not Thunderbolt displays).