# How to connect two Macbook Pro 2020 to one Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have a Thunderbolt Display (27-inch) and two Macbook Pro 2020. I tried to connect them both to the Thunderbolt Display using [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407085/405119) approach but it didn't work for me.

Is there a way to do this connection without having to unplug the cable and switch between Macbooks manually?

Thank you!

EDIT: I did purchase [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08D6LFJXB) cables instead of the ones listed in the solution provided, to make sure they were compatible with Macbook Pro 2020 but it's still not working.

Comment: The poster in that other question seems to insist that their solution would work, but I can't see how.  Yes, if the monitor in question was a DisplayPort one, but they claim to have an Apple Thunderbolt monitor.

Comment: [Do you need a KVM?](https://www.kvm-switches-online.com/us3310.html) It’s not clear how thunderbolt would allow you to choose which of the two macs controlled a display if at all it would work. Physically all the connectors would connect, but the bus wouldn’t activate all three devices for video.

Comment: @bmike you're right, I don't see how the thunderbolt display would allow me to choose between the two Macbooks. I'm starting to think that getting another monitor would be the best solution.