# HDMI to DisplayPort adapter for a M1 MacBookPro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hdmi, displayport, apple-silicon

At my new job, I received an Apple MacBookPro to work on. Some specs: 16-inch 2021, Apple M1 Pro CPU, one HDMI port.

> ***This Mac has USB-C ports and does not have any legacy mini DisplayPorts.***

Can you recommend me an adapter (not a cable) HDMI male to DisplayPort female, to connect to my office DisplayPort-based monitors? Most of my google searches returned the exact opposite adapters (i.e. DisplayPort male to HDMI female) and I have no clue if they are compatible with "my" Mac.

I'm asking for an adapter because I already have plenty of things to carry with me every-day (i.e. a docking station with a power adapter, essentially two bricks).

It seems some **clarifications / updates** are needed:

1. I'm not interested in all Apple's history and how they moved one technology to other platforms/device versions/etc -> I want an adapter that works with my config.
2. I want something that is **not device dependent** so that I could use it, for example, with a video card if I want, or another windows/linux notebook (which might not have usb-C). This is why I've asked for an adapter from HDMI.

Comment: The laptop supports DisplayPort natively, there's no reason to mess around with a HDMI adapter just to talk to a DisplayPort monitor.  Pick up a USB-C to DisplayPort cable.

Comment: I fail to to see the wisdom of making this question a duplicate where all the posted answers at the duplicate are useless with respect this question. The Mac referred to in the [duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199560/where-can-i-purchase-female-thunderbolt-to-hdmi-cable) uses mini DisplayPort and this Mac uses USB-C. ***The cables in the other answers would not plug into this Mac!***

Comment: The dupe directly answers the the question about going from HDMI to DP.  The port form factor is irrelevant here whether it’s DP, mDP, or Type C; the answer is still the same. The generation of Mac is also irrelevant because the technology applicable to both  questions hasn’t changed.

Comment: @MarcWilson I had specifically written in English that I don't want cables

Comment: There is no adapter that goes from HDMI to DP.  If you have a DP monitor, you need to use the Type C port as it has the DP signal. What do you have there now?

Comment: @Allan: Are you sure there is no adapter that goes from HDMI to DP. I ask because I googled and quickly found [this one](https://www.cablecreation.com/products/hdmi-to-displayport-adapter-with-usb-power?currency=USD&variant=41121855733931&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&gclid=CjwKCAiA2fmdBhBpEiwA4CcHzU2flma2_bAGViC855w0U5mceYRRGx-64nPjWiZT5htDbVZe-akrghoCNGQQAvD_BwE).

Comment: radui: Enough. You want an answer that covers everything. All versions of macOS, OS X, Linux and Windows. All PC's and Macs with HDMI ports. All Monitors and other such devices which take DP as input. Covers all HDMI and DP specifications and revisions. And finally, works with all known video resolutions. I hope you can understand why I think your question needs more focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Your latest edit has changed your question to focus more on converting HDMI to DisplayPort and less on your Mac itself. In fact, you actually state ***"not device dependent"***. IMO, you should have posted your question at [superuser](https://superuser.com) instead.

After a quick google, I found Cable Creation offers the [HDMI to DisplayPort Adapter with USB Power](https://www.cablecreation.com/products/hdmi-to-displayport-adapter-with-usb-power?currency=USD&variant=41121855733931&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&gclid=CjwKCAiA2fmdBhBpEiwA4CcHzU2flma2_bAGViC855w0U5mceYRRGx-64nPjWiZT5htDbVZe-akrghoCNGQQAvD_BwE) (SKU: CD0764). With respect to needing power, you should read my [updated answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453123/macbook-pro-m1-hdmi-to-vga-adapter/453141#453141) to your other question.

[image]

BTW: USB type C ports are the future. Current and future Macs and PCs will use this port for the following:

- As a DisplayPort which can be converted to VGA, DVI, HDMI, etc through the use of adaptors and/or active/passive cables.
- USB 1.1, 2.x, 3.x and 4.x which may require an adaptor.
- Thunderbolt 3 and/or Thunderbolt 4.
- Power Delivery.

---

### Orignal Answer

The HDMI port is for connecting the Mac to a monitor or similar device which also has a HDMI port. Since you want to connect to a DisplayPort-based monitor, you should use one of the USB Type C ports. When connected properly, a USB Type C port on your Mac operates as a display port.

> Note: The cable or adaptor needs to support DP alt mode which is also supported on your Mac.

An example cable would be the [StarTech.com® CDP2DPMM6B 6' USB-C to DisplayPort Adapter Cable; Black](https://www.quill.com/startechcom-cdp2dpmm6b-6-usb-c-to-displayport-adapter-cable-black/cbs/52654019.html?effort_code=369&sfcp=1&gclsrc=aw.ds&&cm_mmc=SEM_PLA_SHOP_N_7p_52654019_N_N_ZOM&mcode=SEM_PLA_ZOM_7p_52654019_N_N&gclid=Cj0KCQiAtvSdBhD0ARIsAPf8oNn-z7sBjYZq78hLky08UtAuxiEvIbcKaRZdDIzE89Xqu8SFqiUwWbIaAjWSEALw_wcB).

Brand: StarTech.com
Model: CDP2DPMM6B

[image: cable]

The description contains the following:

- **USB-C to DisplayPort adapter cable:** Your MacBook Pro has USB Type C ports and the monitor has a DisplayPort.
- **for use with USB-C devices that support DP alt mode:** This would be your MacBook Pro.

I suppose an alternative would be to use an adaptor such as [USB-C to DisplayPort Adapter 8K 60Hz](https://www.cablecreation.com/products/usb-c-to-displayport-adapter-8k-60hz?currency=USD&variant=41121745502379&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&gclid=Cj0KCQiAtvSdBhD0ARIsAPf8oNn0e0-tEsrClvpeAkAEjr1JjCwTlfnZg8Q0xscZ5HV_oUlL3cVpQrIaAkohEALw_wcB). The description given also explicitly states the use of DisplayPort alt mode. Here you would also need a DisplayPort cable.

Brand: Cable Creation
Model (SKU): CD0719

[image: adaptor]