# MacBook Pro M1 HDMI to VGA adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, apple-silicon, vga-adapter

At my new job, I received an Apple MacBookPro to work on. Some specs: 16-inch 2021, Apple M1 Pro cpu, one HDMI port.

Can you recommend me an adapter (not a cable) HDMI male to VGA female, to connect to VGA monitors?

I have a HDMI to VGA adapter (produced by Well) that's working for Dell notebooks, but not on my Mac; so, I would like to avoid buying another incompatible one. The adapter works with the docking station I also received from my company, but having essentially 2 bricks and an adapter ... is not something I would like to carry with me or continue seeing on my desk.

It seems some **clarifications / updates** are needed:

1. I'm not interested in all Apple history and how they moved one technology to other platforms/device versions/etc -> I want an adapter that works with my config.
2. I want something that is not device dependent so that I could use it with a video card if I want, or another windows/linux notebook (which might not have usb-C), that's why I've asked for an adapter from HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

I have a 2018 Mac mini with Mojave installed. I have an old Akai HD TV which is connected though the TV's HDMI port to the Mac. The connection to the Mac has been either directly to the Mac's HDMI port or USB type C port through an adaptor.

I recently updated the Mac to a Mojave/Ventura dual boot arrangement. Under Ventura, the TV's HDMI port is not longer compatible with the Mac. This is true regardless of whether I use the HDMI port or an USB type C port on the Mac. So, I learned the following.

> The HDMI connection can be dependent on the version of the operating system you are using.

The TV has a VGA port, so I purchased the [j5create JDA203 HDMI to VGA Adapter with Audio](https://www.microcenter.com/product/612946/j5create-jda203-hdmi-to-vga-adapter-with-audio-%E2%80%93-hdcp-22-compliant) (Model JDA203), shown below.

[image: adaptor]

The printed documentation, which came with the adaptor, stated external power was probably not required when used with a PC, but may be necessary when used with a Mac. Sure enough external power was needed, which is not included with the adaptor. Due to the distance between the Mac and TV, I powered the adaptor using a old phone charger, which was plugged into a 120 VAC outlet. From this, I learned the following.

> The HDMI port on your Mac may not be capable of powering your adaptor.

Finally, the adaptor could not read the available resolutions from the TV and therefore could not report the available resolutions to Ventura. This was solved by temporarily attaching the adaptor to a (assumed newer) monitor, selecting 1080p from Ventura, then moving the adaptor back to the TV. This fix work well until power was removed from the adaptor, which resulted in the 1080p resolution setting being lost.

---

### Orignal Answer

Similar to you other question,

Like your [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453120/hdmi-to-displayport-adapter), you should use an adaptor which supports DisplayPort alt mode. Your Mac has USB Type C ports which automatically switch to supply DisplayPort signals when the appropriate monitor (or other device) is connected by the corrected cable and/or adaptor. For example, there is [this adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZR19CCY) which explicitly states the use of DisplayPort (DP) Alt Mode.

Brand: StarTech.com
Model: CDP2VGAW

[image: adaptor]

If you prefer, you can also use a cable. For example, there is [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072DX5Z5S), which supports DisplayPort (DP) Alt Mode.

Brand: Plugable
Model: USBC-VGA-CABLE

[image: cable]

In this case, there is a chip in the cable which acts as the adaptor. The description given in the [above link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072DX5Z5S) states the following:

> "DisplayPort signaling is converted to VGA by a chip in the adapter cable."